# Finding duplicate rows by one column and that they have other column different

Tags: sql

I need a query to get rows with duplicate values in a columnn and different in other. For instance, if I have:

```
definition
bat     job  ....   .....
Hi      apple
Hi      babana
Bye     apple
Bye     apple
```

I need obtain:

```
bat      job    job
Hi       apple  babana
```

I try with these query but don't works :-(

```
select a.bat, a.job, b.job from definition a inner join definition b on
( a.bat=b.bat and
  a.job <> b.job
  and a.bat in (select bat from definition group by bat having count(*)>1));
```

Please any help? Thanks

Comment: can you explain with a more clear example. How is (bat,job,job) to be obtained from the data set provided. And why isnt (Bye,apple) in the list

Comment: bye,apple isn't in the list becuase the two columns have same values. I need first get all rows with duplicates values in bat columns and then analyze second column job and if the job values are differents these rows are what the query must obtain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use aggregation:

```
select bat, min(job), max(job)
from t
group by bat
having min(job) <> max(job);
```

Comment: Thanks, but i the table definition have other line with "Hi orange"? With your query only shows two columns right?

Comment: @absolute333 . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  If you have a different question, then ask it as a NEW question.